# Using Angular.js to create multiple views displaying different parts of the same model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning Angular right now and I'm practicing by writing a simple application that uses `ngRoute` based on [this example](http://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend).

```
<-- index.html -->
<html>
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code from the example displays information about various "Javascript Projects". My question is, how would I create yet another view that displays information about this model?

Say, for example, that I wanted to create one more `ngView` further down the page that only displays the project names without their descriptions? (See [the example](http://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend))

It seems like I would have to distinguish them from each other somehow. Maybe like this?

```
<body>
    <div ng-view="fullView"></div>
    ...
    <div ng-view="projectNameView"></div>
</body>
```

But I don't see anything like that in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/Book/Gatsby), so I think that's probably incorrect. Then I thought maybe I am supposed to use a separate controller like this:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="fullViewController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div ng-controller="projectNameViewController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But then the `ngView`s still seem to be undistinguished from each other.

What is the right way to do this? Once I have an idea from the `index.html` side, I think I can work out the javascript/module side myself - I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into ui-router: http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

It provides nested views and easier state management than the default Angular router.

Answer (score 2):

Actually only one `ng-view` is supported per `route` and for sure that is a down-side of this approach.

As @Jakemmarsh pointed http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router is option worth considering. Though you have to be aware of:

> **Warning:** UI-Router is pre-beta and under active development. As such, while this library is well-tested, the API is subject to change. Using it in a project that requires guaranteed stability is not recommended.

Some directives that maybe helpful of achieving multiple templates on a single page are:

1. `ng-include` -- it includes template/html from a different file.
2. `ng-switch` -- switches rendering of `html` on some conditon.
3. `ng-if` -- renders if condition is met.